# Svelte component styles aren't overriding global styles

Tags: sass, svelte, sveltekit

I am using scss in a Sveltekit project and have included my main global styles in my root layout file.

```
<script lang="ts">
  import 'css/app.scss'
</script
```

In my global styles, I have the style:

```
button {
  padding: 0;
}
```

In a component, I have added this local style:

```
<style lang="sass">
  button {
    padding: 1rem;
  }
</style>
```

When the site renders, the local style is overridden by the global style. I can add !important to the local style, but I am looking for a way to have the local style always take precedence over the global style.

Thank you in advance for you suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

In your component you can use a CSS selector with higher specificity to make the CSS code in a CSS rule there take precedence over CSS code elsewhere. For example, in a selector, classes have higher specificity than tag names, so in your component you can in your HTML code add a `class="theButton"` to the `<button>` element, and then in your CSS code use `.theButton` instead of `button` as selector.